# Executor Service and scheduleWithFixedDelay()

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Here is my task. I have a static queue of jobs in a class and a static method that adds jobs to the queue. Have n amount of threads that poll from a queue and perform the pulled job. I need to have the n threads poll simultaneously at an interval. AKA, all 3 should poll every 5 seconds and look for jobs.

I have this:

```
public class Handler {

    private static final Queue<Job> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void initialize(int maxThreads) { // maxThreads == 3

        ScheduledExecutorService executorService =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(maxThreads);

        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Job job = null;
                synchronized(queue) {
                    if(queue.size() > 0) {
                        job = queue.poll();
                    }
                }
                if(job != null) {
                    Log.log("start job");
                    doJob(job);
                    Log.log("end job");
                }
            }    
        }, 15, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

}
```

I get this output when I add 4 tasks:

```
startjob
endjob
startjob
endjob
startjob
endjob
startjob
endjob
```

It is obvious that these threads perform that jobs serially, whereas I need them to be done 3 at a time. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is the polling actually required, or is that just an implementation detail to get jobs from your queue into your thread pool?

Comment: Just a tip, but it's probably better to submit a task with the `Job` instead of synchronizing/polling in Runnable on `queue`; that sort of defeats the purpose of parallel execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

So you must schedule three independent tasks to have them run concurrently. Also note that the scheduled executor service is a fixed thread pool, which is not flexible enough for many use cases. A good idiom is to use the scheduled service just to submit tasks to a regular executor service, which may be configured as a resizable thread pool.

Comment: The deleted answer said to call scheduleWithFixedDelay() 3 times. And it seems to work. Not sure why he deleted it. I need to remain at 3 because of system resources. Accept in a min.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `ScheduledExecutorService` with fixed delay, what means, that your jobs will run  one after one. Use fixed thread pool, and submit 3 threads at a time. Here is [an explanation with examples](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `Job extends Runnable` then your code simplifies dramatically:

First declare the Executor somewhere globally accessible:

```
public static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
```

Then add a job like this:

```
executor.submit(new Job());
```

You are done.